# vim shortcuts - how do i know if there exists already a shortcut

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I'm a vim newby and i try to make my own custom shortcuts...

But I have following question:

How do I know if I'm remapping a built in shortcut? 
Do I have to know all shortcuts before I know if I overwrite something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can display them with the `:map` command. Read `:help map`  & [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Displaying_the_current_Vim_environment) for more info.

```
:map
```

Other variants are:

```
:nmap - normal mode mappings
:vmap - visual mode mappings
:imap - insert mode mappings
```

Comment: is there a possibility to grep these things? i dont know how to do this.. thanks for the answer!

Comment: You can type them in `vim` as it is. For example, open `vim` and type `:map`.

Comment: yeah i know, but i want to filter the output of :map? there are so many keys and its hard to read all

Comment: oh sorry. You can provide the mapping to the `:map` for that. For example in my session, `:map ,w` returns `n  ,w          * <C-W>v<C-W>l`

Comment: If you really want to `grep` them, you can redirect all your mappings to a file using `:redir`.

`:redir! > path/to/file.txt`
`:map`
`:redir END`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to map something, you could always check has been it mapped to something already or not by

`:verbose map {your mapping here}`